# SQL Server 2016 Standard Edition Replication

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2016

I have a single database running on SQL Server 2016 Standard edition in our primary datacenter. I would like to keep a live copy as close to realtime (1-2 minutes) in our disaster recovery datacenter so when the primary goes down we can redirect the traffic to DR. When the primary is back, changes in DR need to sync back to the primary.

From what I've researched peer-peer isn't available in the Standard edition. I found (and lost) a doc that discussed how to do this in Standard edition. It was limited to one database with one primary and one backup, yet I can't figure out what I searched to find it.

Any suggestions on best practice to accomplish this sync?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replication is not a DR technology in SQL Server, so you should never consider that for DR purposes. In SQL 2016 Standard Edition, you should look at [Basic Availability Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/basic-availability-groups-always-on-availability-groups?view=sql-server-2017).

Setting up a Basic AG for this database will provide you with DR capabilities and will allow for failover without breaking the flow of data between your replicas.

Comment: Thanks... I've read about availability groups and I am a bit confused. When failed over is the DR database fully functional and will it sync back to the primary when the primary becomes available again?

Comment: Yes, once a failover occurs, the DR node becomes the new Primary and will synchronise log records back to the original primary once it is available again.